# How to compare text in buttons on android

Tags: android

I want If the button has the text `start` execute start capture.

and if the button has the text `stop` execute stop capture.

```
if { //button text is start
   //start capture
} else if { //button text is stop
   // stop capture
}
```

how to compare text in buttons on android?

Comment: button. getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("start")

Answer (score 0):

```
if(button.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("start")){
//start capture
}else if (button.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
// stop capture
}
```

try this hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Always use switch for nested if else statements

```
switch(button.getText().toString()){
case "start":
//start capture
break;
case "stop":
// stop capture
break;
}
```

> It is always checking all conditions in nested if else
>   statements. But in switch case it will go to the relevant case only,
>   won't check all the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

String btnText = button.getText().toString();

if (btnText.equalsIgnoreCase("start")){

  //something here
}
```

-Or-

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);;

if(btn.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(text)){

   //something here

}
```

Comment: wrong `if (btnText == "start")` . why you set `==` .??

Answer (score 0):

```
if(button1.getText().toString().equals("Start")){

}else if(button2.getText().toString().equals("Stop")){

}
```